# Qt/Sqlite вствка в БД

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

У меня такая проблема. Пытаюсь по нажатию кнопки выполнять SQL запрос по добавлению данных в БД, но ничего не выходит, а выводится ошибка:

> QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")

В чем может быть проблема? Заранее благодарю.

```
QString requester = ui->requester_l->text();
QString IPN = ui->ipn_l->text();
QString description = ui->description_t->toPlainText();
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO request (requster,ipn,description)"
              "VALUES (?,?,?)");
query.bindValue(0,requester);
query.bindValue(1,IPN);
query.bindValue(2,description);
bool qur = false;
qur= query.exec();
qDebug()<<qur<<query.lastError()<<"\n"<<query.lastQuery();
```

Comment: Много параметров, проверьте таблицу и типы ключей в ней. Если вы пытаетесь вставить значение в поле ключа с автоинкрементом, то получите ошибку, кажется это тот случай.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена переименованием столбца requester в иное